# Android listview item click

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to get into a listview items have different action when pressed, this action depends on a variable "state", but the problem is that all the items are in the same action, here the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String  codigo = c.getString(TAG_CODIGO);
                    String  asignatura = c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE);
                    int  estado  = c.getInt("estado");
                    final int maxhoras = c.getInt("maxhoras");
                    final String idprogramacion = c.getString("programacionid");

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_CODIGO, codigo);
                    map.put(TAG_NOMBRE, asignatura);

                    jsonlist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvclases);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Bienvenida.this, jsonlist,
                            R.layout.listview,
                            new String[] { TAG_CODIGO,TAG_NOMBRE, }, new int[] {
                            R.id.codigo, R.id.nombre,
                    });
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    if(estado == 1) {
                        Log.e("estado", ""+estado);
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Bienvenida.this, registroAsistencia.class);
                                i.putExtra("programacion",  idprogramacion);
                                i.putExtra("maxhoras",  maxhoras);
                                startActivity(i);
                                /*Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correcto: el usuario existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast1.show();*/
                                //Toast.makeText(Bienvenida.this, "You Clicked at " + jsonlist.get(+position).get("asignatura"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(Bienvenida.this, "la clase aún no ha comenzado " + jsonlist.get(+position).get("asignatura"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

I am working on android studio, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acually, this is not an answer to your question. But after watching your code it seems that you are not implementing `ListView` in a correct way.

A simple way to work with `ListView` goes through following abstract steps:

Make your Collection Ready -> Prepare the Adapter from the collection -> Set this adapter to ListView

In your case, assuming you are calling web services for getting data and your web services is responding with JSON array.

Now, make a POJO(plain old Java object) class like:

```
public class MyListItem{
    private String codigo;
    private String asignatura;
    private int estado;
    private int maxhoras;
    private String idprogramacion;

    public MyListItem(String codigo, String asignatura, int estado, int maxhoras, String idprogramacion){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.asignatura = asignatura;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.maxhoras = maxhoras;
        this.idprogramacion = idprogramacion;
    }

    // you can write getter setter methods for this
    public int get_estado(){
        return estado;
    }

    public String get_idprogramacion(){
        return idprogramacion;
    }

    public int get_maxhoras(){
        return maxhoras;
    }

    public String get_asignatura(){
        return asignatura;
    }
}
```

Now, prepare list like:

```
ArrayList<MyListItem> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
    mArrayList.Add(
        new MyListItem(
            c.getString(TAG_CODIGO),
            c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE),
            c.getInt("estado"),
            c.getInt("maxhoras"),
            c.getString("programacionid")
        )
    );
}
```

Now, you are ready with list, just pass it to your custom adapter. If you are not aware of preparing Custom Adapter, check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).

Once you are ready with making custom adapter, pass the list to this adapter like:

MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, mArrayList);

**Note:** Above line strictly depends constructor of your custom adapter, say, `MyCustomAdapter`

After that, you are ready with your adapter, set it to your ListView, like:

`list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Now, here you set the `OnItemClickListener`

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
         MyListItem item = (MyListItem)parent.getItem(position);
         if(item.get_estado() == 1)
         {
             Intent i = new Intent(Bienvenida.this, registroAsistencia.class);
             i.putExtra("programacion",  item.get_idprogramacion());
             i.putExtra("maxhoras",  item.get_maxhoras());
             startActivity(i);
         }
         else{
             Toast.makeText(Bienvenida.this, "la clase aún no ha comenzado " + item.get_asignatura(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

      }
});
```

Hope you get what you are trying to achieve..

This should help you out.

Comment: You're welcome :) if it helped you, you can accept the answer. So that visitor can understand about correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two different onClickListeners(), try using only one and move your if-else block inside of the onItemClick() method

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
         if(estado == 1) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Bienvenida.this, registroAsistencia.class);
              i.putExtra("programacion",  idprogramacion);
              i.putExtra("maxhoras",  maxhoras);
              startActivity(i);

         } else {
                   // Do something else
         }
       }
   });
```

Comment: I have already tried and does not work, keep doing the same action

Comment: What do you see when you click?

Comment: when I click on any item, always performing the same action that is in the else.

Comment: That means your `estado` value is not equal to one. Where have you set your value for `estado`? Include that part of your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `estado` variable, it's global varible, so When you use `listview.setOnItemClickListener(...)` that mean all the item in `listview` will be the same action with your above code.

Solution is you should create your own `custom adapter` and then implement `OnItemClickListener` in your `adapter`, base on different states to set different actions for item . Also you can `setOnClickListener` in `getView()` in `Adapter` and base on state also.

Please refer as below :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
     int estado = -1;
     // you should do something like this
    /* ********** */
     YourItem item = ((YourItemsData)data).get(position);
     estado = item.getState();
     /* ********** */
     if(estado == 1) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Bienvenida.this, registroAsistencia.class);
          i.putExtra("programacion",  idprogramacion);
          i.putExtra("maxhoras",  maxhoras);
          startActivity(i);

     } else {
               // Do something else
     }
   }
```

});